# as.POSIXct Not Recognizing 9 AM

Tags: r, posixct

I have some intraday data where the index is formatted like

```
c('20140304 95700', '20140304 95800', '20140304 95900', '20140304 100000')
```

When I try to convert the character strings to a `datetime` object using `as.POSIXct`, the conversion doesn't recognize any of the times that happen in the ninth hour and it appears to be because they aren't preceded by a 0.

For example, when I run

```
data$DATE <- as.POSIXct(data$DATE, format = "%Y%m%d H%M%S", tz = "EST5EDT")
```

everything after the ninth hour is formatted correctly. It's only the data in the ninth hour that is returned as an NA. Any ideas on how to address this issue?

Comment: I don't know if this issue is addressed by POSIXct, but would you consider inserting a leading zero to all hours before 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is safe to assume that all times that have 5 digits should have a leading zero, here is a way to insert those zeros.

```
times <- c('20140304 95700', '20140304 95800', '20140304 95900', '20140304 100000')
new.times <- sub("(.* )(\\d{5})$", "\\10\\2", times)
as.POSIXct(new.times, format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
#[1] "2014-03-04 09:57:00 CST" "2014-03-04 09:58:00 CST" "2014-03-04 09:59:00 CST" "2014-03-04 10:00:00 CST"
```

The pattern in the `sub` call have 2 sets of parenthesis:

`(.* )`: this is anything, any number of times, followed by a space
`(\\d{5})$`: this is 5 digits.  The `$` means that the 5 digits come at the end of the string

The second argument specifies the replacement for strings that match the pattern. `\\1` means "the first group", which in this case is everything before the "time" part of the string.  `\\1` means "the second group", which is the 5 digit times.  i.e. `\\10\\2` inserts a zero between the first group and the second group.

---

You could also use `strsplit` and `lapply` to insert the zeros.  This will be slower.

```
sapply(strsplit(times, " "), 
       function(x) paste(x[1], if (nchar(x[2]) == 5L) paste0("0", x[2]) else x[2]))
#[1] "20140304 095700" "20140304 095800" "20140304 095900" "20140304 100000"
```

Answer (score 1):

The comments given to you by jinlong are correct.  you need leading 0s in your hours.  So append them to your strings.

```
dates <- c('20140304 095700', '20140304 095800', '20140304 095900', '20140304 100000')
```

Better yet convert your character strings into a proper format like '2014-03-04 09:57:00' to avoid nasty surprises.

Furthermore, the positioning of your `%`'s is not right in

`as.POSIXct(data$DATE, format = "%Y%m%d H%M%S", tz = "EST5EDT")`

It should be like this (for your appropriate time zone -- "" should give default for your settings):

`as.POSIXct(data$DATE, format = "%Y%m%d %H%M%S", tz = "", origin = '1970-01-01')`